# When deploying a job, is it possible that the command returns after the deployment is complete?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using maven to deploy my jobs on Google Cloud Dataflow, with the folowing command :

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.beam.StreamerRunner --Dexec.args="\
...
--runner=DataflowRunner \
..."
```

It deploys successfully, and it is pulling the log from the dataflow job and printing them on the output. I'm wondering if it is possible to tell the deployment to not pull and just returns.

Indeed, my CI tool (TeamCity) I'm using to deploy my job, is also waiting never ending.

I obviously can run the maven command in a `nohup`, but maybe an option does exist to exit the command after the deploy is complete.

Comment: My pipeline jobs only pulls logs and waits like this if I explicitly call `waitUntilFinish()` on the `PipelineResult` object. You're making it sound like yours is doing it by default?

Comment: Thank you @Alex I'm indeed calling this method. I will check tomorow if that's working better without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex pointed out I was calling waitUntilFinish in my code, so it dit exactly what I asked it to do.

It was fixed as soon as I removed the calle to

`waitUntilFinish()`